# Calling methods from EL. Why doesn't this work?

Tags: java, jsp, el

And how can I make it work?

```
<%

    class thing {

        public String doit () { 
            return "doing it";
        }

    }

    request.setAttribute ("thing", new thing ());

%>


<body>
    ${requestScope.thing.doit ()}
</body>
```

I don't have the freedom to create a separate compiled class. It must be inline.

Thanks.

Comment: If you use getter notation then you can say `thing.doit`.

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to the request because the scriptlet is server side and a better use will be

```
<%
        public String doit () { 
            return "doing it";
        }
%>


<body>
   <%
doSomething();
%>
</body>
```

With this you call your function. But in the end this is a **very Bad Practice** to use scriptlets. It's hard to debug. Hard To read, etc, etc. Read a lot of good answers in SO [Like this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3177733/how-to-avoid-java-code-in-jsp-files)

Comment: Thanks, but not really an answer to my question. I didn't ask for another way of doing it (which I know and I know about the "Bad Practice" of using scriptlets but it's not really my decision to make).